# Wrong IP from GCP kubernetes load balancer to app engine's service

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm having some troubles with a nginx pod inside a kubernetes cluster located on GCP which should be able to access a service located on app engine.

I have set firewall rules in the app engine to deny all and only allow some ips but the ip which hits my app engine service isn't the IP of the load balancer of my Nginx but instead the IP of one of the node of the cluster.

An image is better than 1000 words, then here's an image of our architecture :

[image]

The problem is: The ip which hits app engine's firewall is IP A whereas I thought i'd be IP B. IP A changes everytime I kill/create the cluster. If it were IP B, I could easily open this IP in App engine's firewall rules as I've put her static. Anyone has an idea how to have IP B instead of IP A ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The IP address assigned to your nginx "load balancer" is (likely) not an IP owned or managed by your Kubernetes cluster. Services of type `LoadBalancer` in GKE use Google Cloud Load Balancers. These are an external abstraction which terminates inbound connections in Google's front-end infrastructure and passes traffic to the individual k8s nodes in the cluster for onward delivery to your k8s-hosted service.

Pods in a Kubernetes cluster will, by default, route egress traffic out of the cluster using the configuration of their host node. In GKE, this route corresponds to the gateway of the VPC in which the cluster (and, by extension, Compute Engine instances) exists. The public IP of cluster nodes will change as they are added and removed from the pool.

A workaround uses a dedicated instance with a static external IP to process egress traffic leaving your VPC (i.e. egress from your cluster). Google has a tutorial for this purpose here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-a-nat-gateway-with-kubernetes-engine

There are k8s-native solutions, but these will be unsuitable in a GKE context at present due to the inability to maintain any node with a non-ephemeral public IP.

Comment: Thank you @Cosmic Ossifrage, I'll dig into it.